# mysql: schema for many to many related data with extra parameters

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, relational-database

Hi I have two Models one is `Composition` and one is `Salts`, `Every composition is the combination of one or more salts`, now there is another term **quantity** which differentiate two composition with same salts i.e.

if ***x composition has 2 salts A(250 mg) and B(350 mg)*** and

***y composition also have same salts A (350 mg) and B(500 mg)***

so my question is in which table the **quantity must be stored** I can make a many to many table to related only composition and salts id,

Also I want that all the composition  should be **unique** so what method should I follow in validation?

Comment: I guess by "all the composition should be unique" you mean that no two compositions have the same set of salts and quantity pairs? Please write this requirement clearly.

Comment: I guess by "what method should I follow in validation" you mean what constsraints you should declare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to interested in making statements of the form:

```
-- [c] is a composition number
composition(c)
-- [s] names a salt
salt(s)
-- composition [c] uses salt [s] in quantity [300] mg
composition_salt_quantity(c,s,q)
```

A design is based on fill-in-the-blank statements that you can use to describe your application stituation. Each predicate has a table. The table holds the rows that make a true statement by giving values for the named blanks. Eg Here having (7,'NaCl',300) in table composition_salt_quantity states "composition 17 uses salt 'NaCl' in quantity 300 mg" and leaving it out states "it is not the case that composition 17 uses salt 'NaCl' in quantity 300 mg". You must decide on what predicates you want. The above is based on your (unclear) (original) question. The following checks variations and gives constraints. (In your (unclear) edited question it seemes like maybe you want "composition [c] uses salt [s] in quantity [300] of unit [u]".)

If a composition uses a salt then there is only one quantity. So (c,s) is unique in composition_salt_quantity. If a salt can be used by multiple compositions then (s) is not unique. If a composition can use multiple salts then (s) is not unique. So (c,s) is a candidate key. So declare (c,s) UNIQUE NOT NULL. You have to tell me, but almost certainly no other set of columns is unique. So (c,s) is the only candidate key. You can declare one candidate key PRIMARY KEY instead. Here there is only one.

Question: Do you need

```
-- composition c has salt s
composition_salt(c,s)
```

If you want to record that composition c uses salt s without mentioning a quantity then you need composition_salt. Use the same reasoning as above re whether (c,s) is a candidate key and so UNIQUE NOT NULL or PRIMARY KEY. Then because a (c,s) in composition_salt_quantity would be in compositon_salt there would be a composition_salt_quantity FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES compositon_salt (c,s).

But if you want to always record the quantity when you record that composition c uses salt s then you don't need composition_salt. Because: For every row (c,s) in it you must have a row (c,s,q) in composition_salt_quantity stating that composition c has salt s in quantity q. And for every row not in it, it's false that composition c has salt s so it's false that for some q composition c has salt s in quantity q so there's no row in composition_salt_quantity with that c and s. So a (c,s) is in compositon_salt if and only if it is in composition_salt_quantity. So composition_salt is not needed. (It's value is always `select c,s from composition_salt_quantity`.)

Similarly: Only if you want to record a composition without recording it in another table do you need composition(c). The constraint is that composition_salt_quantity (c) is a FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES composition (c). (Same for composition_salt if you have it.) Only if you want to record a salt without recording it in another table do you need salt(s). The constraint is that composition_salt_quantity (s) is a FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES salt (S). (Same for composition_salt if you have it.) You say "every composition is the combination of one or more salts" but it is not clear whether you mean in the application situation or also in the tables.

(You should actually decide whether you need tables on (c,q), (s,q) and/or (q). And if you have any pair of two-column tables then decide whether that would make composition_salt_quantity unnecessary. And if you have three whether one is unnecessary.)

Comment: Thanks but can you give me some example for that? because it is difficult to understand

Comment: I edited my answer. 1. What is the first thing you don't understand? 2. Please react to my comment on your question. My answer shows how to be clear about what goes into a table. Edit your question. 3. My answer has some "if"s. Is each one true or false? Edit that into your question. 4. Please explain "some example". I gave you one answer and the "if"s tell you when and how to make a different answer.

Comment: Thanks again Sir, I almost got my solution but for the perfect answer I edited my question. Hope it helps you to understand my problem.

Comment: Sorry for your inconvenience, my English is not very good and also have less idea about posting question here, although as you asked yes composition can use multiple salts and also a salt can be used by multiple composition.I marked your answer accepted because with the little help of PHP it solved my problem.